# How to detect trigger cause by artifactory trigger in jenkins pipeline project (groovy script)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I want to detect job build cause which is trigger by Artifactory plugin. what should I write for cause statement?

I know to detect user, time, scm, or upstream trigger job. It as follows:

```
    //Check if the build was triggered by SCM change
    scmCause = upStreamBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.SCMTriggerCause)
    if (scmCause != null) {
        return scmCause.getShortDescription()
    }

    //Check if the build was triggered by timer
    timerCause = upStreamBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.TimerTriggerCause)
    if (timerCause != null) {
        return timerCause.getShortDescription()
    }

    //Check if the build was triggered by some jenkins project(job)
    upstreamcause = upStreamBuild.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause.class)
    if (upstreamcause != null) {
        job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(upstreamcause.getUpstreamProject(), hudson.model.Job.class)
        if (job != null) {
            upstream = job.getBuildByNumber(upstreamcause.getUpstreamBuild())
            if (upstream != null) {
                return upstream
            }
        }
    }
    return;
```

I expect some command like:

```
artifactorCause = upStreamBuild.getCause(hudson.triggers.ArtifactoryTrigger.ArtifactoryTriggerCause)
```

so I can have a short description of the trigger.

Comment: Would you please rephrase and format (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) your question properly? It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: I am using multiple trigger mechanism to trigger job in Jenkins. Like timeTrigger, ScmTrigger, and Artifactory plugin trigger. My question is How can I find out which trigger has trigger the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on [this javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/artifactory/org/jfrog/hudson/trigger/ArtifactoryCause.html) I would say

```
artifactoryCause = upStreamBuild.getCause(org.jfrog.hudson.trigger.ArtifactoryCause)
```

Comment: To slightly extend this answer (which was exceptionally helpful) ... the url of the file which caused the trigger is given by the call:

`artifactoryCause.getUrl()`